# Jmeter how to build up from 0 to 1500 after 30 minutes

Tags: jmeter

I need to build up from 0 to 1500 after 30 minutes
End with 1500 visitors at the same time
There are 3 test scripts.

What do I need to fill in into the thread group?

I was thinking about:
number of threads(user) 1500
Ramp-up-period in seconds = 1800

But I am not sure if this is right

Update.
I have it now like this.

[my instalation now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkTXN.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is more or less right, just make sure to set the next values in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group):

1. Tick `Infinite` box next to "Loop Count"
2. Tick `Specify Thread Lifetime` box and provide the desired test duration (for example below setup gives you another 30 minutes with 1500 users)

   [image]

You might find [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) easier to use, they can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/), for instance here's how your setup will look like for the [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/)

[image]

you can see the chart of the anticipated load and the impact of any workload changes

Comment: So this will grow the total amount of users till 1500 at 30 minutes?

Above setup is for 60 minutes in total?  If I need only 30 minutes in total I can ignore the specify thread lifetime.  Am i right?

Comment: thank you for your great help.
Can you please also check the picture that I did add?  It are 3 scenario's

Hope it is ok like this.  Hope to hear from you (or someone else) soon

Comment: If you need 30 minutes only - use 1800 as the Thread Lifetime. Other assumptions are correct